# Prove that there exists $\sqrt[3] 7 \in R$, real number cube of which is 7.

Tags: real-analysis

Today on the seminar, I was given the task to prove the existence of the $\sqrt[3] 7$. Our instructor provided us with the following solution

> Method of finding a lion in a desert. Given a desert we divide it by 2. Then we build a wall and take the part where there is a lion. Then we divide it by 2, build a wall...
> $z = \sqrt[3] 7 $ $\to$ $0 < z^3 <8$ $\to$ $0 < z < 2$. Divide by 2.
> $[0, z_1 = 1] \cup (z_1, 2]$ Since $z^3 > z_1$ we take the right part, interval $[z_1, 2]$...

I did not understand the following solution at all. Could you please explain how did we prove that cubic root exists ?

Comment: This concerns how reals are defined. If you define the reals via Dedekind cuts, this would be easy...

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that for any real number $x$ there exists a real number $y$ with $y^3 = x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/651234/prove-that-for-any-real-number-x-there-exists-a-real-number-y-with-y3-x)

Comment: @Kumar Thanks, Kumar, but I have no problem with proving this statement. I just did not understand this solution, until VIVID wrote it down.

Comment: I have not heard it described as a method of finding a lion in a desert but this algorithm is well known and very useful.  I would call it: binary chop.  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm#:~:text=In%20computer%20science%2C%20binary%20search,middle%20element%20of%20the%20array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope there is no problem with understanding the part $0\le z \le 2$ or $z \in [0,2]$. Then we divide the segment into equal parts to get two segments, namely $[0,1)\cup[1,2]$. Since $1^3 < 7$ and $2^3>7$, we must have $\sqrt[3] 7 \in [1,2]$ (if exists). Then, we repeat the process. By $n^\text{th}$ step, we will have a segment of length $\cfrac{1}{2^n}$ which tends to $0$ as $n$ tends to infinity. Say, we have got the sequence of nested segments $[a_n,b_n]$. Here, both sequences $a_n$ and $b_n$ are convergent since $a_n < b_1$ and $b_n > a_1$ for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and they are definitely increasing and decreasing, respectively. Also, since the length of segments goes to $0$, we must have $$\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = \lim_{n\to\infty} b_n = L$$ for some $L \in [1,2]$. Note that this $L$ satisfies $L^3=7$ since we did all the cutting job to locate this point. $\square$